# integrate symfony and ajax

Tags: ajax, symfony, post

I need to send data using ajax in Symfony2 action.
For this I use the following js code:

```
$.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "{{ path('slch_create_slot',{ 'uuid': meeting.uuid })}}",
            data: request,
            cache: false,
            success: function(){
               alert(data);
                    location.href = "{{ path('slch_new_meeting_step2',{ 'uuid': meeting.uuid })}}";
            } 
        });
```

Symfony2 side I use the following code:

```
 if($request->isXmlHttpRequest()){
        $json = $request->getContent();
        $tableau = json_decode($json, true);
        var_dump($tableau);
        ....
        $response = new Response(json_encode(array('response' => 'ok')));
        $response->headers->set('Content-Type', 'application/json');

        return $response;

    }
```

When retrieving the Symfony2 response I get the following results:

```
    array(1) {
  ["slots"]=>
  array(4) {
    [0]=>
    array(5) {
      ["hour"]=>
      string(2) "14"
      ["minute"]=>
      string(1) "0"
      ["day"]=>
      string(2) "11"
      ["month"]=>
      string(1) "1"
      ["year"]=>
      string(4) "2015"
    }
    [1]=>
    array(5) {
      ["hour"]=>
      string(2) "14"
      ["minute"]=>
      string(1) "0"
      ["day"]=>
      string(2) "12"
      ["month"]=>
      string(1) "1"
      ["year"]=>
      string(4) "2015"
    }
    [2]=>
    array(5) {
      ["hour"]=>
      string(2) "14"
      ["minute"]=>
      string(1) "0"
      ["day"]=>
      string(2) "13"
      ["month"]=>
      string(1) "1"
      ["year"]=>
      string(4) "2015"
    }
    [3]=>
    array(5) {
      ["hour"]=>
      string(2) "14"
      ["minute"]=>
      string(1) "0"
      ["day"]=>
      string(2) "14"
      ["month"]=>
      string(1) "1"
      ["year"]=>
      string(4) "2015"
    }
  }
}
{"response":"ok"}
```

can you tell me why I have the request in the Symfony2 response ?

Comment: you're doing var_dump($tableau) which dumps the request. That's why you're receiving it. Get rid of that line and you won't receive it anymore.

Comment: it's not clear what you're asking.. What request do you have in what response?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you're doing var_dump($tableau) which dumps the request. That's why you're receiving it. Get rid of that line and you won't receive it anymore. –  acontell 1 hour ago